# Programa no muestra ninguna salida del modulo al que llamo python

Tags: python

Tengo 2 modulos: El modulo principal y el modulo femenino

Lo que quiero es un aplicar un patron factory donde el modulo "principal" me elija cual modulo llamar (modulo femenino o modulo masculino)

Lo llama dependiendo del genero que yo le ponga. Sin enbargo cuando lo ejecuto el programa compila bien pero no me da absolutamente ningun resultado

Principal :

```
    import femenino
    import masculino
    
    class elegir_genero(): # elegir genero
            
        def elegir_persona(self,nombre,genero,edad):
            if (genero is 'Femenino'):
                return femenino.mujer
            elif (genero is 'Masculino'):
                return masculino.hombre
    
    ana = elegir_genero()
    ana = ana.elegir_persona('Ana','Femenino

','10')
```

Modulo femenino:

```
class mujer():
    def  __init__(self,nombre,genero,edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.genero = genero
        self.edad = edad
        print('{} es una mujer de {} años de edad'\
.format(self.nombre,self.edad))
```

La salida que deseo es :
"Ana es una mujer de 10 años de edad"

Cual error estoy cometiendo ?

Comment: un __init__ solo se ejecuta si instancias una clase, ya que es el constructor. ¿donde has instanciado `mujer()`? Solo veo `femenino.mujer` pero sin las `()` solo es una referencia, no una instancia.

Comment: Muchas gracias Saelyth. Tambien me faltaba instanciar los parametros del contructor dentro de los parentesis. Ya obtuve el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Saelyth tienes toda la razon.

El problema estaba en que debia agregar los paréntesis en las instancias en la clase "elegir_persona" en el modulo "principal" pero ademas agregar los argumentos de del methodo **init** .

Es decir :

def elegir_persona(self,nombre,genero,edad):

```
if (genero is 'Femenino'):
         
     return femenino.mujer(nombre,genero,edad)
```

Y perfecto. Asi instancio la clase con sus respectivos argumentos en el constructor.

Comment: Consejo: Una forma más "pythonica" de hacer las condiciones sería `if genero == 'femenino':`. Normalmente no usamos parentesis a menos que tengamos que usar varias lineas para un condicional. Igualmente, cuidado porque `is` no es lo mismo que `==`. Los iguales comprueban si el Valor es el mismo. El `is` comprueba si la Referencia a un objeto es la misma. Deberías buscar documentación sobre esta diferencia antes de que te crees un mal hábito al respecto. Aprender mal luego da problemas dificiles de corregir.